# Vimperator Keybinding, Requires Additional Keypress

Tags: vim, vimperator

I'm really new to Vim/Vimscript, and I'm trying to configure my .vimperatorrc to execute the same as when I run `:open google search-term`.

From reading, it looks like I need `nnoremap g :open google<Space>`.  It almost works, but the window doesn't appear until I press another key.

Is there something else I need to do?  To be clear, I'd like it to basically do this same thing, but not require an additional keypress to open the search window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're attempting to use a mapping and there's a hesitation before things show up in the command line, it can indicate that Vimperator has more options beyond what you've pressed so far. It's waiting for more keypresses to see if the ambiguity is resolved by either A) matching a mapping that has more characters (where no remaining ambiguity exists) or B) not matching anything else and thereby going with the shorter mapping that did match. I'll demonstrate first by using examples with a leader key and then come back to your specific question.

Let's say you have the following in your `.vimperatorrc` file (and assume that your leader key is the default, `\` (see `:h mapleader`)):

```
nnoremap <leader>g :open google<space>
```

As soon as you finish typing `\g`, `:open google` will appear as you expect. However, let's say you have this in your `.vimperatorrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>g :open google<space>
nnoremap <leader>gw :open google wiki<space>
```

Now, after you type `\g`, nothing visibly happens (unless you look very closely to the left of the current URL, which shows your command mode keypresses as you type them). This is because Vimperator is uncertain whether you want that `\g` mapping, or if you intend to also press a `w` to complete the `\gw` mapping. In this scenario, you can type the command `:nmap \g` (don't press `<enter>` yet), and you'll see those two mappings.

In your scenario, however, you are mapping the character `g`. Vimperator has many actions tied to key combinations that begin with the letter `g`. For instance, `gt` & `gT` are "move to next/previous tab." (Since these are default keybindings, they will not be displayed for you as you type the command `:nmap g`.) It might be possible to unmap all of the default `g[another character]` mappings, but it would be unorthodox and probably unhealthy. In order to prevent clashes with default keybindings, convention would encourage you to use the leader key with your custom mappings as demonstrated above.